# How to manage propagation and isolation with @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I'm new of spring and I'm trying to learn how to works its transactional context.

I have a service that read from a file and persist a few entity bean

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl{

@Autowired
MyObjectService myObjectService;


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void readFromFile() throws Exception {
    //Do something
    checkAndSave();     
}   


public void checkAndSave() throws Exception {

    List<MyObject> objects = myObjectService.readAll();

    for(MyObject myObject : objects){

        boolean check1 = myObjectService.check1();

        if(check1){
            myObjectService.save(myObject);
        }

    }

}
```

}

```
@Service
public class MyObjectServiceImpl implements MyObjectService{

    @Repository
    MyObjectRepository myObjectRepository


    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<MyObject> readAll(){ 
        myObjectRepository.findAll()
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public boolean check1(){

        //run a few select to check somethings
    }
```

}

My questions are:

The method checkAndSave will run in a transaction?
The method checkAndSave will run in the same transaction of the readFromFile method?

And also i noted that if i put the @Transactional annotation on the readFromFile method,the application takes much longer  time than running without annotation.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have transactional on check1 and readAll method? you should use transaction when modifying the db.

Save method will run in its own transaction and not in same as the read method. 
It takes much longer in a transaction because it verifies everything before it executes.

Comment: To give to the underlying data store the opportunity to apply those optimizations as it sees fit. But maybe together to readOnly I should use also the propagation attribute?